# Reusing bitcoin hw wallet infrastructure as a PGP replacement?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, pgp, bip32-hd-wallets

A lot of people who own Bitcoin are already know how to securely generate, store and use their BIP32 + BIP39 wallets, and own hardware wallets.

Are there any existing projects/standards trying to bolt on PGP-like capabilities on top of this existing secure-key infrastructure?

I imagine, that in a perfect world people would just generate their 24 words once in their whole lifetime, and then export some applicatin/device specific derived keys to other (potentially less secure) devices and use these for things like git commit signing, encrypted communication, 2FA, etc. . When the keys get compromised, or it's time to simply cycle them, they could use the determinism to switch to new keys (by just bumping the sequence number in the derivation path) which were known well in advance, but which were never exposed to anything other than the devices handling the master key. Seems like it would simplify and unify a lot of secret-key management, by piggy-backing on what's already being done in Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure how far the development of hardware wallet support for Lightning is, there is an E2EE messaging protocol called "Sphinx chat" based on the Lightning Network. Some HWW also function as smart cards for PGP and general password manager. I'm not aware of a project that aims to provide an email encryption system.